# Reading text lines with fscanf and fgetc

Tags: c, scanf, fgetc

Having trouble with such a little problem. I'm trying to read text from a file. The file is in the form:

```
Jim 3 X Y Z 
James 2 A B
Alley 5 D E F G H
```

Where the integers represent the number of variables that follow. 
I'm reading the name and the number with fscanf, then reading the char variables with fgetc so I can put them in an array. The fscanf part is working fine but I'm missing something with the fgetc.

```
 do {
    c = fscanf(inputFile, "%s" "%d", word, &inputSize); 
    printf("%s ", word);

    while (c!= '\n')  {
        c = fgetc(inputFile);
        printf("char is:%c ", c);
    }
}while (c != EOF);
```

This ends up in an infinite loop. So I tried telling when the fgetc will stop.

```
while (c != EOF){
    c = fscanf(inputFile, "%s" "%d", word, &inputSize); 
    printf("%s ", word);
    printf("%d ", inputSize);
    printf("\n");
    for (i =0;i<(inputSize*2);i++) {
            c = fgetc(inputFile) ;
            if (c== ' ') {
            }
            else {
                 printf("char is :%c ", c);
                 printf("\n");
            }
    }
```

The output becomes:

```
 Jim 3 
 char is :X 
 char is :Y 
 char is :Z 
 James 2 
 char is :A 
 char is :B 
 Alley 5 
 char is :D 
 char is :E 
 char is :F 
 char is :G 
 char is :H 
 Alley 5 
 char is :? 
 char is :? 
 char is :? 
 char is :? 
 char is :? 
 char is :? 
 char is :? 
 char is :? 
 char is :? 
 char is :?
```

What part of the fgetc am I messing up in? Also, why is the fgetc not seeing the '\n' in my first example, but instead infinite looping?

Thanks

Comment: Most probably, `c` is a `char` and not an `int` and you run into problems because the code can't reliably store EOF in a `char`.   However, although you've made a moderate attempt at an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) this isn't quite complete. Is the data being typed or read from a file?  Also, what sort of machine are you compiling on?  Is plain `char` a signed or unsigned type? (I note in passing that the use of string concatenation in the `scanf()` format strings is not exactly wrong, it is unusual.)

Comment: Sorry, I am reading lines from a txt file. Compiling on  a x86-64 machine. Actually had no idea if plain chars are signed or unsigned, but did a quick search and it looks like the default is signed chars on x86 compilers (which I have not changed).

Comment: Did you declare `unsigned char c;` or `char c;`?

Comment: I have been declaring "char c".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original code, you have:

```
char c;   // Per comments
do {
    c = fscanf(inputFile, "%s" "%d", word, &inputSize); 
    printf("%s ", word);

    while (c!= '\n')  {
        c = fgetc(inputFile);
        printf("char is:%c ", c);
    }
} while (c != EOF);
```

This code works correctly until after you've read the newline after `Alley`'s data.  Then you go back to the top of the loop, and read some data with `fscanf()`.  Since there is no data, `fscanf()` returns EOF, but you go ahead and print what was in `word` and `inputSize` before.  Then you go into an infinite loop because the `fgetc()` returns EOF, which is not `\n`, so you try again, and again, and …

Fixes:

1. `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`.  On a system where plain `char` is a signed type, this means you mistake a valid character (often ÿ, U+00FF, LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS) for EOF.  On a system where plain `char` is an unsigned type, nothing matches EOF.  Neither behaviour is correct.
2. Test for EOF or newline; always think about that.
3. Test the return from `fscanf()`; if it isn't 2, things have gone wrong.

And I'd use a top-checking `while` loop rather than a bottom-checking `do … while` loop.  There are occasions for a `do … while` loop; this is not, in my opinion, one of them.

The analysis for the revised code is similar.  Your code is:

```
char c = 0;
while (c != EOF){
    c = fscanf(inputFile, "%s" "%d", word, &inputSize); 
    printf("%s ", word);
    printf("%d ", inputSize);
    printf("\n");
    for (i =0;i<(inputSize*2);i++) {
            c = fgetc(inputFile) ;
            if (c== ' ') {
            }
            else {
                 printf("char is :%c ", c);
                 printf("\n");
            }
    }
}
```

Again, you need to check the value returned by `fscanf()` and bail out of the loop if it is not 2.  The first three `printf()` calls could be combined into one.
After you read `Alley`'s data the first time, the `fscanf()` returns EOF, but you ignore this and print the data again.  Then you go into the `fgetc()` loop which gets EOF mapped to ÿ (0xFF) but this is not a blank, so you print it (by itself, 0xFF is not a valid byte in UTF-8, which may account for the question mark that's printed).  When you've finished doing 10 iterations, `c` contains a code that expands to EOF, so the loop terminates.

Fixes:

- Roughly the same as before.
- Use `int char;`
- Check the return from `fscanf()` before proceeding.
- Check for the desired character or EOF in your `fgetc()` loops.

#### Possible fix for original code:

```
int c;
while (fscanf(inputFile, "%s%d", word, &inputSize) == 2)
{
    printf("%s (%d)\n", word, inputSize);

    while ((c = getc(inputFile)) != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        if (c != ' ')
            printf("char is: %c\n", c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, awesome thanks! Those EOF and '\n' checks pretty much solved it. But completely overlooked checking the fscanf return.